# powershell invoke-webrequest to log into website

Tags: forms, powershell, web, authentication

I have been having a lot of success using invoke-webrequest to log in to websites but I'm stumped. I am trying to log into `https:// ctslink.com` or `https:// direct.ctslink.com`. The login form has a hidden token field which changes every time I try to login, I believe is what is causing the problem. Another thing I noticed was the session variable `$fb` is null after the first call to invoke-webrequest.

```
$r=Invoke-WebRequest www.ctslink.com -SessionVariable $fb

$form = $r.Forms[0]


$form.Fields["userId"] = "MyUsername"
$form.Fields["passwd"] = "MyPassword"

$r=Invoke-WebRequest 'https://ctslink.com/login.do' -WebSession $fb  -Body $form.Fields
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated,
Mike

Answer (score 10):

Don't put a $ for the session variable argument. Try this -

```
$c = $host.UI.PromptForCredential('Your Credentials', 'Enter Credentials', '', '')
$r = Invoke-WebRequest 'http://1.2.3.4/' -SessionVariable my_session
$form = $r.Forms[0]
$form.fields['username'] = $c.UserName
$form.fields['password'] = $c.GetNetworkCredential().Password
$r = Invoke-WebRequest -Uri ('http://1.2.3.4' + $form.Action) -WebSession $my_session -Method POST -Body $form.Fields
```

Comment: Nice catch with the extra $ in the SessionVariable but the login still doesn't seem to go through. It seems like it just reloads the page when I attempt to login with the second Invoke-WebRequest. All of the inputs look good and the $form.Action has the action and the jsessionID so I'm running out of ideas. The only other thing that I think may be tripping it up is the hidden token in the form, pasted below, the token changes with every invoke even though I am passing $fb.          
 
 
 

<input type="hidden" name="org.apache.struts.taglib.html.TOKEN" value="b0334c048ba4451b8fd2c7ed65b40433">

Comment: @Mike use Chrome's developer tools and analyze what's happening with your cookies and session.

Comment: Thanks, don't have too much experience using those tools but have been giving it a shot. The only thing that seems to change in the cookies is the TLTHID, not entirely sure what that is but it does change and has a response one. Here is what I see. Would I need to feed the response cookie to the site? 

.

Request Cookies
168
JSESSIONID
S9r4T2QphZRqgynGvTwJff2v7NB0C8TXTxpJ3YKwLPB1XLr4Dbp4!-1983783621!1872934036
88
TLTHID
A300E618298A102982CEAC7E32202CE6
39
TLTSID
514C4E862988102918F1E900AE7B46D5
41
Response Cookies
47
TLTHID
AC6DDFDA298A10297CC097D28AEFE7FE
/
Session
47

Thanks again, 
Mike

Comment: Put `$form` on a line by itself to see a list of fields the form expects

Comment: If there are multiple forms on the page then increment the Form pointed. `$form = $r.Forms[1]` etc

Comment: @AndyArismendi This is a longshot, but I'm writing a powershell script to log into a webpage and download a file, this code works for doing this on powershell 5, but when running it in powershell 7 throws a bunch of null array errors, any idea what's going on?