# Powershell Invoke-WebRequest Login to website not working

Tags: powershell

I am trying to write a Powershell script that will login to and navigate a website. When trying to POST the login credentials, however, I'm getting the error "Server Error in '/Webpostage' Application.". I have no issue with logging in manually using a browser. I've tried using the same URI for both requests as well as using the Developer network monitor in Chrome to capture the actual URI of the POST (shown below). Any ideas?

```
$Username = "username"
$Password = "password"

# GET Stamps.com Login page
$R = Invoke-WebRequest https://print.stamps.com/webpostage/signin/default.aspx -SessionVariable StampsCom
$Form = $R.Forms[0]

# Fill in login credentials
$Form.Fields["UserNameTextBox"] = $Username
$Form.Fields["PasswordTextBox"] = $Password

# Login to Stamps.com
$R = Invoke-WebRequest -Uri ("https://print.stamps.com/webpostage/ajax/AuthenticateUser.aspx?LoginSource=SigninPage" + $Form.Action) -WebSession $StampsCom -Method POST -Body $Form.Fields
```

Comment: You're appending `$Form.Action` _directly_ to the Ajax URL, without any separator, which seems odd. I imagine you need either another query field, or perhaps you don't need `$Form.Action` at all in this case?

Comment: Hi @mklement0, even if I remove the "+ $Form.Action", I still get the same error. I was just following the example here (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25336275/powershell-invoke-webrequest-to-log-into-website). Thanks!

Comment: If you follow that example, you'd have to use `'https://print.stamps.com' + $Form.Action`.