# powershell parser html5 site

Tags: javascript, powershell, html-parsing

I need to log on site, and parse info.
I am trying to do this: [powershell invoke-webrequest to log into website](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25336275/powershell-invoke-webrequest-to-log-into-website)
But I can not find the form...
If I use function view page source in the browser I see only:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1">
<meta name="theme-color" content="#ffffff"><link rel="icon" href="/frontend/favicon.ico">
<link href="/frontend/css/99.ad9d8c.css" rel="stylesheet"><link href="/frontend/css/style.aa5ad6.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>
<div id="content"></div>
<script src="/frontend/js/modules/vendors~index.ad9d8c.chunk.js"></script>
<script src="/frontend/js/index.275be7.bundle.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Update
I am try next, but this not work for me.

```
$ieObject = New-Object -ComObject 'InternetExplorer.Application'
$ieObject.Navigate('http://XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX:8090/frontend/login')
$currentDocument = $ieObject.Document
$currentDocument.IHTMLDocument3_getElementsByTagName("input") | Select-Object Type,Name
```

Error

```
 You cannot call a method on a null-valued expression.
```

Comment: Powershell web automation is usually done with Selenium, in my experience. Here is a reasonably good tutorial, though I haven't use Selenium myself in several years (I've nothing to automate): https://adamtheautomator.com/getting-started-in-web-automation-with-powershell-and-selenium/

Comment: @Tomalak I tried this, but it didn’t work for me https://www.gngrninja.com/script-ninja/2016/9/25/powershell-getting-started-controlling-internet-explorer, maybe your now other method?